# Calculating choices in multiple choices model

Tags: python, django

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    #choices
    NEGATIVE = -1
    NEUTRAL = 0
    POSITIVE = 1
    FEEDBACK_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (NEGATIVE, 'Negative feedback'),
        (NEUTRAL, 'Neutral feedback'),
        (POSITIVE, 'Postive feedback'),
    )
    #database fields
    short_description = models.CharField('Short opinion: ' ,max_length=100, default='SOME STRING')
    text = models.TextField('Detailed opinion: ', max_length=300, default='SOME STRING')
    feedback = models.IntegerField('Feedback choice: ', max_length=3, choices=FEEDBACK_TYPE_CHOICES, default = 1)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    #def reputation(self):
    #     return ((self.positivefeedback-self.negativefeedback)/(self.positivefeedback+self.neutralfeedback+self.negativefeedback))*100


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email  = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    eddies = models.IntegerField()
    premium = models.BooleanField()
    feedback = models.ForeignKey(Feedback, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I'm trying to archive model OneToMany, where 1 User can have multiple feedbacks. How can I archive a function that could calculate the feedback outcome score of a specific user?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change your code as below, It might work as you want

```
NEGATIVE = -1
    NEUTRAL = 0
    POSITIVE = 1
    FEEDBACK_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (NEGATIVE, 'Negative feedback'),
        (NEUTRAL, 'Neutral feedback'),
        (POSITIVE, 'Postive feedback'),
    )

feedback = models.IntegerField('Feedback choice: ', max_length=3, choices=FEEDBACK_TYPE_CHOICES, default = 1)
```

You are passing default value 1 as integer but you have char field. So I guess it won't work. replace your code with mine
make sure that you remove quotes from choice we need to pass values as integer

Answer (score 1):

For this relation, "*User has many Feedbacks*", the Feedback class should have stored the User it corresponds to instead of the reverse which you have now.

Then you can fetch a list (queryset) of Feedbacks which contain a specific user using:

```
Feedback.objects.filter(user=user_you_want)
```

Where "user_you_want" is an object of User class

Comment: I think it should be user.objects.filter("user_you_want").values_list("feedback__feedback")

Comment: There are many problems with this: 1st: you are trying to get 1 User object only. As so "Users.objects.get" should be used. 2nd: "user_you_want" is not a string but a variable. Then.. values_list will convert a queryset (which will not exist now) to a list.. well.. that.

Comment: Yes,it looks like